# Why are my buttons not being enabled by Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, button

I have a shopping cart with a finalize purchase button. I'd like to have a functionality that if I press the finalize purchase button the "purchase" buttons on the product cards (which were in the cart) are disabled since they are already purchased. The cart and the cards are different components.

cart.component.ts - on click this function is being called

```
  purchaseDisabled(product:Product){
product.purchased=true;}
```

card.component.ts - i have two possibilities here:

```
buttonDisabled: boolean;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.buttonDisabled=false;
  }
    purchasedProduct(){
      if(this.productItem.purchased=true){
        this.buttonDisabled = true;
      }
    }
```

or

```
  button = document.querySelector('button');

    purchasedProduct(){
      if(this.productItem.purchased=true){
       this.button?.disabled 
      }
    }
```

Now I have two problems: if I click the finalize button, then I get this error:

> core.js:6498 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined
> (setting 'purchased')

and also the buttons on the cards are disabled always when the page is loaded.

Do you know how could this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the object productItem has not been initialized before calling the method,therefore you have this error, and since you're using Angular, you should almost always use the first option, and it isn't what's causing the issue.

Be sure productItem !== null before calling the method, I suggest you do it in the ngOnInit method, but it depends on the flow of your app.